# Custom action missing from WooCommerce Order actions Metabox dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

With the help of [this page](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/) I've added an additional email to the WooCommerce emails. I wanted it te be a manual email that I can send to the customer, but it's not showing up in the order in the dropdown list of emails to send. I'm guessing I'm missing something, but I don't know what. This is de code of the plugin I use:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Custom Order Email
 * Plugin URI: http://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/
 * Description: Demo plugin for adding a custom WooCommerce email that sends admins an email when an order is received with expedited shipping
 * Author: SkyVerge
 * Author URI: http://www.skyverge.com
 * Version: 0.1
 *
 * License: GNU General Public License v3.0
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 *
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 *  Add a custom email to the list of emails WooCommerce should load
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @param array $email_classes available email classes
 * @return array filtered available email classes
 */
function add_expedited_order_woocommerce_email( $email_classes ) {

    // include our custom email class
    require_once( 'includes/class-wc-expedited-order-email.php' );

    // add the email class to the list of email classes that WooCommerce loads
    $email_classes['WC_Expedited_Order_Email'] = new WC_Expedited_Order_Email();

    return $email_classes;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_expedited_order_woocommerce_email' );
```

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 * A custom Expedited Order WooCommerce Email class
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @extends \WC_Email
 */
class WC_Expedited_Order_Email extends WC_Email {


    /**
     * Set email defaults
     *
     * @since 0.1
     */
    public function __construct() {

        // set ID, this simply needs to be a unique name
        $this->id = 'wc_expedited_order';

        // this is the title in WooCommerce Email settings
        $this->title = 'Factuur herinnering';

        // this is the description in WooCommerce email settings
        $this->description = 'Deze mail kan handmatig worden vestuurd ter herinnering. Factuur zit in de bijlage.';

        // these are the default heading and subject lines that can be overridden using the settings
        $this->heading = 'Herinnering factuur';
        $this->subject = 'Herinnering factuur';

        // these define the locations of the templates that this email should use, we'll just use the new order template since this email is similar
        $this->template_html  = 'emails/customer-reminder.php';
        $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/customer-reminder.php';

        // Trigger on new paid orders
        //add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
        //add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification',  array( $this, 'trigger' ) );

        // Call parent constructor to load any other defaults not explicity defined here
        parent::__construct();

        // this sets the recipient to the settings defined below in init_form_fields()
        $this->recipient = $this->get_option( 'recipient' );

        // if none was entered, just use the WP admin email as a fallback
        if ( ! $this->recipient )
            $this->recipient = get_option( 'admin_email' );
    }


    /**
     * Determine if the email should actually be sent and setup email merge variables
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @param int $order_id
     */
    public function trigger( $order_id ) {

        // bail if no order ID is present
        if ( ! $order_id )
            return;

        // setup order object
        $this->object = new WC_Order( $order_id );

        // bail if shipping method is not expedited
        /* if ( ! in_array( $this->object->get_shipping_method(), array( 'Three Day Shipping', 'Next Day Shipping' ) ) )
            return; */

        // replace variables in the subject/headings
        $this->find[] = '{order_date}';
        $this->replace[] = date_i18n( woocommerce_date_format(), strtotime( $this->object->order_date ) );

        $this->find[] = '{order_number}';
        $this->replace[] = $this->object->get_order_number();

        if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() )
            return;

        // woohoo, send the email!
        $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
    }


    /**
     * get_content_html function.
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_html() {
        ob_start();
        woocommerce_get_template( $this->template_html, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading()
        ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }


    /**
     * get_content_plain function.
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_plain() {
        ob_start();
        woocommerce_get_template( $this->template_plain, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading()
        ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }


    /**
     * Initialize Settings Form Fields
     *
     * @since 2.0
     */
    public function init_form_fields() {

        $this->form_fields = array(
            'enabled'    => array(
                'title'   => 'Enable/Disable',
                'type'    => 'checkbox',
                'label'   => 'Enable this email notification',
                'default' => 'yes'
            ),
            'recipient'  => array(
                'title'       => 'Recipient(s)',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( 'Enter recipients (comma separated) for this email. Defaults to <code>%s</code>.', esc_attr( get_option( 'admin_email' ) ) ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'subject'    => array(
                'title'       => 'Subject',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( 'This controls the email subject line. Leave blank to use the default subject: <code>%s</code>.', $this->subject ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'heading'    => array(
                'title'       => 'Email Heading',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( __( 'This controls the main heading contained within the email notification. Leave blank to use the default heading: <code>%s</code>.' ), $this->heading ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'email_type' => array(
                'title'       => 'Email type',
                'type'        => 'select',
                'description' => 'Choose which format of email to send.',
                'default'     => 'html',
                'class'       => 'email_type',
                'options'     => array(
                    'plain'     => __( 'Plain text', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'html'      => __( 'HTML', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'multipart' => __( 'Multipart', 'woocommerce' ),
                )
            )
        );
    }


} // end \WC_Expedited_Order_Email class
```

I've commented out the triggers and added the code for it to be a manual customer mail.

```
    function is_customer_email() {
        return true;
    }

    function is_manual() {
        return true;
    }
```

In the WooCommerce settings I see the mail and it looks like a manual mail that can be send to the customer. The mailtemplates look good, but I don't see the name of the mail in the dropdown in the order to really send it.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to add "Send Expedited email" action to "ORDER actions" Metabox dropdown as follow:

```
// Adding 'Send Expedited email' to action Metabox dropdown in admin order pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_actions', 'filter_wc_add_send_expedited_email_action', 20, 1 );
function filter_wc_add_send_expedited_email_action( $actions ) {
    $actions['send_expedited_email'] = __( 'Send Expedited email', 'woocommerce' );

    return $actions;
}

// Trigger the email notification on 'Send Expedited email' action (composite hook)
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_send_expedited_email', 'trigger_action_send_expedited_email', 20, 1 );
function trigger_action_send_expedited_email( $order ) {
    // Get all WC_emails objects instances
    $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    // HERE We define our custom email class name
    $class_name = 'WC_Expedited_Order_Email';

    // Send custom email
    if( class_exists($class_name) ) {
        $wc_emails[$class_name]->trigger( $order->get_id() );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> I didn't really tried with your custom email code, as the custom related templates are missing from your answer code… You should add your complete code to a public Gist on Github and then add the link to your answer (useful for the community).

Comment: Thanx, that did work! You used the woocommerce_order_actions filter to tie the mail to that metabox. Is there a similar filter for the second dropdown? Not the actions, but the send email metabox below the actions? (So that a note is made that the specific email was sent).

Comment: @Arne What dropdown? do you mean the order status dropdown? In this case is not possible as it's related to order status only.

Comment: Nevermind, the pdf invoice plugin I use a lot adds a send email metabox. Thought it was standard functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
function sv_wc_process_order_meta_box_action( $order ) {

    // add the order note
    $message = sprintf( __( 'Herinnering verstuurd door: %s.', 'label20-textdomain' ), wp_get_current_user()->display_name );
    $order->add_order_note( $message );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_send_expedited_email', 'sv_wc_process_order_meta_box_action' );
```

to make a note with the username of the user doing the action.